# SQL to select highest row of a combination of two columns

Tags: mysql, sql, groupwise-maximum

I need help with a query for MySQL 5.5

I'm trying to only select 1 line per combination of 2 columns (tan, location_id) after sorting the rows by location_id, count_number, try_number. So basically I want to have a query that returns only the yellow rows from the following picture. Only the 1 record per combination of tan/location_id with the highest "count_number" und "try_number" within that group.

[image]

This is the query that I currently have.

```
select tan, quantity, count_number, try_number, location_id 
from inventario_inventoryregistry
where tan = '53-100554-01'
order by location_id desc, count_number desc, try_number desc;
```

Comment: See also: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max

Answer (score 1):

I think this does what you want:

```
select iir.*
from inventario_inventoryregistry iir
where (count_number, try_number) = (select iir2.count_number, iir2.try_number
                                    from inventario_inventoryregistry iir2
                                    where iir2.tan = iir.tan and iir2.location_id = iir.location_id
                                    order by iir2.count_number desc, iir2.try_number desc
                                    limit 1
                                   );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select tan, quantity, count_number, try_number, location_id
from
(select tan, quantity, count_number, try_number, location_id, row_number() over (partition by location_id, tan_id order by location_id desc, count_number desc, try_number desc) rw_nm
from inventario_inventoryregistry
where tan = '53-100554-01')
where rw_nm = 1;
```